# Robotium: searchText vs clickOnText

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I have a strange situation:
On a screen, I have the following string to click on: "1 Year Basic License ($15.00)"

But the following code give me some headache:
assertTrue(solo.searchText("1 Year Basic License ($15.00)"));
solo.clickOnText("1 Year Basic License ($15.00)");

The test fails on the clickOnText statements! saying (in the log):
1 Year Basic License ($15.00) not found. Have found: 1 Year Basic License ($15.00)

Can someone give me some hint to understand what's happening...

Regards,
Alban.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found was going on ;)

Everything here is around the interpretation of the string parameter as a regexp!
So the solution here is to escape the dollar character!

Bye,
Alban.